# Change git structure

Tags: git, version-control, repository

Currently I have the following folder structure:

```
root
  .git (folder)
  Folder A
     SubFolderA
     ...
  Folder B
  ...
```

And I want the following structure:

```
root
  Folder A
    .git (folder)
     SubFolderA
     ...
  Folder B
  ...
```

How can I do this without destroy my current repo?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to move `.git`? If you move `.git` into `folder A`, this will cause files out of `Folder A` (`Folder B`) are not version controlled by git any more.

Comment: **Why** do you want/need to move the .git folder? You should rarely care about this folder at all.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT `Folder B` and the rest (except `folder A`) are not really important for the repository purpose. I made a mistake when I created the repo by adding `folder B` to the git, so it doesn't matter that `folder B` are not version controlled by git any more.
(sorry if I made a mistake writing this, english is not my first language :P)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen as Marina said, I just want to git tracks folder A, not the rest of files/folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want that, then go ahead and move it:

```
$ mv .git FolderA/
$ cd FolderA/
$ git add .
```

But notice how all files in `FolderB` will now be out of source control:

```
$ git commit -m "Remove all but FolderA from source control"
[master d044479] Remove all but FolderA from source control
 10 files changed, 5 deletions(-)
 rename FolderA/FileInA1 => FileInA1 (100%)
 rename FolderA/FileInA2 => FileInA2 (100%)
 rename FolderA/FileInA3 => FileInA3 (100%)
 rename FolderA/FileInA4 => FileInA4 (100%)
 rename FolderA/FileInA5 => FileInA5 (100%)
 delete mode 100644 FolderB/FileInB1
 delete mode 100644 FolderB/FileInB2
 delete mode 100644 FolderB/FileInB3
 delete mode 100644 FolderB/FileInB4
 delete mode 100644 FolderB/FileInB5
```

You don't have to worry about these other files if you want to read them later, their history is not lost.

For example, if you decide to roll back this commit you can always do that:

```
$ git reset --hard @^
```

Notice how this will recreate a second copy of `FolderB` under `FolderA/FolderB`:

```
..
├── FolderA
│   ├── FolderA
│   │   ├── FileInA1
│   │   ├── FileInA2
│   │   ├── FileInA3
│   │   ├── FileInA4
│   │   └── FileInA5
│   └── FolderB
│       ├── FileInB1
│       ├── FileInB2
│       ├── FileInB3
│       ├── FileInB4
│       └── FileInB5
└── FolderB
    ├── FileInB1
    ├── FileInB2
    ├── FileInB3
    ├── FileInB4
    └── FileInB5
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was harder than this. I omitted the obvious answer lol

Comment: And how can I delete `folder B` and the rest from git history?

Comment: Use `filter-branch` command. `git help filter-branch`, or perhaps [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/), or search SO for answers.